# Pthread scheduling FIFO, RR mixed results

Tags: c, pthreads, scheduling, round-robin

We are trying to analyze the effect of different schedule algorithms on a Ubuntu system for Pthreads. We create several (1,2, 4) threads and let them run on 1, 2 or 4 CPU's. Each thread is a for loop with 1 mathematical operation. 1 threads takes several seconds to finish.

When starting 2 threads on 1 CPU with FIFO they finish a great amount of time apart (logical, FIFO finishes the first created thread first). For RR they finish closer together (half a second difference in some cases). This is al as expected. Now we run each test 10 times and about 1/3rd of the measurements takes half as long as other. We measure the time for all threads to finish. So on 1 CPU we wait for 2 threads to finish. RR or FIFO makes little difference. But running the test multiple times can give you about 6s for 2 or 3 times and about 12s for 5 or 6 times. The extraordinary thing is that there are no occasions where the program finished around 9 or 10 seconds. Its or between 5 and 6 or between 11 and 13. We did these measurements for 4,2,1 threads on 4, 2 ,1 CPU('s). FIFO and RR. Priority has been set both to 0 and to 99 (real-time). No heavy application was using the CPU. on the used core more than 97% of the CPU time went to threads spawned by our program.

When using SCHED_OTHER we have no such phenomenon.

Has anyone got an explanation for this behavior?

It's hard to see how many context switches happen. For FIFO the amount of context switches should be close to 0 and for RR this should be a lot larger but still hardly affecting the total execution time. For SCHED_OTHER I'm guessing the most context switches but I'm not entirely sure.

Another interesting fact is that the total execution time for OTHER is more or less the same as the short time for FIFO with the same amount of threads and CPU's. So FIFO is sometimes as fast as OTHER but sometimes takes double the time.

Regards,

Roel Storms

Comment: Your computer is running, which has threads, which can be scheduled at any time as well.  Might have to do with that.  There's no guarantee with threads!

Comment: To analyze the scheduling of your workload, try using `perf sched record` and `perf timechart`.

Comment: Magn3s1um, I know but double the time is a pretty big influence by a OS that takes only a few percents of CPU resources.
Caf, Thanks for the tip!